# Enabling Secured connections to access Cloud Auth proxy from On-premise

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-sql-proxy

We have a requirement to connect the Cloud SQL Database via Cloud Auth proxy deployed on a GKE cluster from an on-premise application securely.
on-premise -> cloud auth proxy (GKE) -> Cloud SQL Instance. This is working fine when the connections are made on port 8080 but we would like to make it a secured connection from On-premise to Cloud Auth proxy.

#GCP#CloudAuthProxy

We are expecting to connect the Cloud Auth proxy from on-premise servers securely.

#GCP#CloudAuthProxy

Comment: Utilize HTTPS with cloud IAP for enabling secured connections to acess cloud Auth Proxy from on-premise

Comment: Try using HTTPS when utilizing Cloud IAP. First you must [Configure](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-on-prem-howto) Cloud IAP on your GKE cluster in order to mediate access to the cloud. Based on IAM permissions, IAP offers incredibly tight access control for on-premise service accounts.

Comment: Following that, with the IAP service account pointing to the service account you generated for on-premise access, launch the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy. Now set up your on-premises application to use HTTPS port 443 to connect to the cloud SQL Auth Proxy and add the necessary IAM credentials for the service account.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the design here: why hosting a Cloud SQL proxy on GKE, and not directly on premise? In addition, what are the network restriction and route (internal, external, public IP (on the GKE server and/or on Cloud SQL), VPN,...)?

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan from the Google Cloud SQL Proxy team here.

The Cloud SQL Auth Proxy is great for securing connections between a local application and Google Cloud. It is ONLY intended to be run on the same machine as the application.

To secure your connection between your on-prem application and your Cloud SQL instance, please deploy the Cloud SQL Proxy on the same machine as your on-prem application.

[image: network diagram showing that it is safe to deploy the proxy on the same machine as your application, but unsafe to deploy the proxy on a different machine.]